# Como reduzir a quantidade de elifs para encontrar a letra que mais é utilizada no inicio dos nomes?

Tags: python, if, for

```
lista_nomes = []
lista_idade = []
lista_sexo = []
idade_cont_menores = 0
idade_cont_maiores = 0
sexo_op = ['m', 'f']
sexo_cont_masculino = 0
sexo_cont_feminino = 0
cont_maiores_masculino = 0
cont_maiores_femininos = 0
cont_menores_masculinos = 0
cont_menores_femininos = 0
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
          'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
cont_letras = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a = 0

qtn = int(input('Digite a quantidade de pessoas a serem cadastradas: '))

for c in range(0, qtn):
    print('-'*15)

    lista_nomes.append((str(input('Nome: '))).strip().lower())
    if 'a' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(1, ((cont_letras[1])+1))
    elif 'b' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(2, ((cont_letras[2])+1))
    elif 'c' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(3, ((cont_letras[3])+1))
    elif 'd' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(4, ((cont_letras[4])+1))
    elif 'e' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(5, ((cont_letras[5])+1))
    elif 'f' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(6, ((cont_letras[6])+1))
    elif 'g' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(7, ((cont_letras[7])+1))
    elif 'h' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(8, ((cont_letras[8])+1))
    elif 'i' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(9, ((cont_letras[9])+1))
    elif 'j' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(10, ((cont_letras[10])+1))
    elif 'k' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(11, ((cont_letras[11])+1))
    elif 'l' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(12, ((cont_letras[12])+1))
    elif 'm' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(13, ((cont_letras[13])+1))
    elif 'n' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(14, ((cont_letras[14])+1))
    elif 'o' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(15, ((cont_letras[15])+1))
    elif 'p' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(16, ((cont_letras[16])+1))
    elif 'q' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(17, ((cont_letras[17])+1))
    elif 'r' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(18, ((cont_letras[18])+1))
    elif 's' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(19, ((cont_letras[19])+1))
    elif 't' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(20, ((cont_letras[20])+1))
    elif 'u' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(21, ((cont_letras[21])+1))
    elif 'v' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(22, ((cont_letras[22])+1))
    elif 'w' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(23, ((cont_letras[23])+1))
    elif 'x' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(24, ((cont_letras[24])+1))
    elif 'y' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(25, ((cont_letras[25])+1))
    elif 'z' in (lista_nomes[-1])[0]:
        cont_letras.insert(26, ((cont_letras[26])+1))

    lista_idade.append(int(input('Idade: ')))
    if lista_idade[-1] < 18:
        idade_cont_menores += 1
    else:
        idade_cont_maiores += 1
    lista_sexo.append((str(input('Sexo[M/F}: '))).strip().lower())
    if lista_sexo[-1] not in sexo_op:
        print('Está opção é invalida!')
    elif lista_sexo[-1] == sexo_op[0]:
        sexo_cont_masculino += 1
        if lista_idade[-1] >= 18:
            cont_maiores_masculino += 1
        else:
            cont_menores_masculinos += 1
    else:
        sexo_cont_feminino += 1
        if lista_idade[-1] >= 18:
            cont_maiores_femininos += 1
        else:
            cont_menores_femininos += 1

print('-'*15, 'DADOS INSIRIDOS', '-'*15)

print('Nomes: {}'.format(lista_nomes))
print('Idades: {}'.format(lista_idade))
print('Sexo: {}'.format(lista_sexo))

print('-'*15, 'ANALISE DE DADOS', '-'*15)

idade_mais_velho = max(lista_idade)
id_idade_mais_velho = lista_idade.index(idade_mais_velho)
nome_idade_mais_velho = lista_nomes[id_idade_mais_velho]
idade_mais_novo = min(lista_idade)
id_idade_mais_novo = lista_idade.index(idade_mais_novo)
nome_idade_mais_novo = lista_nomes[id_idade_mais_novo]
idade_media = (sum(lista_idade) / (len(lista_idade)))


print('A pessoa mais nova é {} e ele(a) possui {} anos'.format(
    nome_idade_mais_novo, idade_mais_novo))
print('A pessoa mais velha é {} e ele(a) possui {} anos' .format(
    nome_idade_mais_velho, idade_mais_velho))
print('A media entre as idades das {} pessoas é {:.0} anos'.format(qtn, idade_media))

print('\nO numero de maiores de idade é: {}' .format(idade_cont_maiores))
print('Sendo {} mulheres e {} homens' .format(
    cont_maiores_femininos, cont_maiores_masculino))
print('O numero de pessoa menores de idade é: {}' .format(idade_cont_menores))
print('Sendo {} mulheres e {} homens' .format(
    cont_menores_femininos, cont_menores_masculinos))

print('\nO numero de mulheres é: {}' .format(sexo_cont_feminino))
print('O numero de homens é: {}' .format(sexo_cont_masculino))

print('A letra {} é a que mais aparece como inicial! \nAparecendo como inicial {} veses' .format(
    letras[1-(cont_letras.index(max(cont_letras)))], max(cont_letras)))


print('-'*15, 'FIM DA ANALISE', '-'*15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especificamente para a contagem das letras, use um dicionário em vez de uma lista:

```
cont_letras = {}
for c in range(qtn):
    nome = str(input('Nome: ')).strip().lower()
    cont_letras[nome[0]] = cont_letras.get(nome[0], 0) + 1
    lista_nomes.append(nome)
    ...
```

As chaves do dicionário são as letras, e os valores são a respectiva quantidade. Veja que usei `get(nome[0], 0)`, assim, se a letra não existir no dicionário, o valor inicial dela é zero (e já somo 1 em seguida, para indicar que já existe 1 ocorrência desta letra).

Se a letra já existir, sua quantidade é incrementada em 1. Depois, para obter a letra mais frequente:

```
letra_mais_frequente = max(cont_letras.items(), key=lambda d: d[1])
print('A letra {} é a que mais aparece como inicial! \nAparecendo como inicial {} veses'
    .format(letra_mais_frequente[0], letra_mais_frequente[1]))
```

`items()` retorna todos os pares chave-valor, e o *lambda* passado para `key` diz para usarmos o valor. O retorno é uma tupla contendo a chave (letra) cujo valor (quantidade) é o maior de todos no dicionário.

Lembrando que, em caso de empate, somente uma das letras será retornada. Se quiser retornar todas as letras que são mais frequentes, basta percorrer o dicionário procurando todas as chaves cujos valores são iguais ao máximo encontrado:

```
print('As letras mais frequentes aparecem {} vezes, são elas: {}'
    .format(letra_mais_frequente[1], ', '.join(filter(lambda k: cont_letras[k] == letra_mais_frequente[1], cont_letras.keys()))))
```

---

Se bem que para o seu caso, uma opção melhor é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que serve justamente para o que você precisa:

```
from collections import Counter
cont_letras = Counter()

for c in range(quantidade):
    nome = str(input('Nome: ')).strip().lower()
    cont_letras.update([nome[0]])
    lista_nomes.append(nome)
    ...
```

E para obter a letra mais frequente:

```
letra_mais_frequente = cont_letras.most_common(1)[0]
print('A letra {} é a que mais aparece como inicial! \nAparecendo como inicial {} veses'
    .format(letra_mais_frequente[0], letra_mais_frequente[1]))
```